# Error while applying JSON Patch to Kubernetes Custom Resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-custom-resources

I have an instance of a Kubernetes [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) that I want to patch via the Kubernetes API using a JSON patch.

This is my PATCH request:

```
PATCH /apis/example.com/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/mycrd/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json
[other headers omitted for brevity...]

[
  {"op": "replace", "path": "/status/foo", value: "bar"}
]
```

I'm fairly certain that my request body is a valid [JSON patch](http://jsonpatch.com/), and I've previously already successfully updated core (non-CRD) API resources using similar API calls. The CRD has a `openAPIV3Schema` defined that explicitly allows `.status.foo` to exist and to be of type `string`.

The request above is declined by the Kubernetes API server with the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Conent-Type: application/json
[other headers omitted for brevity...]

{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server rejected our request due to an error in our request",
  "reason": "Invalid",
  "details": {},
  "code": 422
}
```

According to the [CRD documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#common-features), CRDs should support `PATCH` request with the `application/json-patch+json` content type. But for some reason, the request appears to be invalid without Kubernetes bothering to tell me *why*. The API server pod did not have any relevant messages in its log stream, either.

The same error also occurs when using `kubectl patch` on the command line:

```
$ kubectl patch mycrd.example.com test --type=json -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/status/foo", "value": "bar"}]'   
The  "" is invalid
```

**What are possible reasons for this error to occur? What options to I have for further debugging?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the (or at least, a partial) answer while still typing the question...

**The Kubernetes API server will not recursively create nested objects for a JSON patch input.** This behaviour is consistent with the [JSON Patch specification in RFC 6902, section A.12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#appendix-A.12):

> **A.12.  Adding to a Nonexistent Target**
>
> An example target JSON document:
>
> ```
> { "foo": "bar" }
> ```
>
> A JSON Patch document:
>
> ```
> [
>   { "op": "add", "path": "/baz/bat", "value": "qux" }
> ]
> ```
>
> This JSON Patch document, applied to the target JSON document above,
> would result in an error (therefore, it would not be applied),
> because the "add" operation's target location that references neither
> the root of the document, nor a member of an existing object, nor a
> member of an existing array.

This is why the original request fails, when the Custom Resources does not have a `.status` property to begin with. The following two subsequent calls (the second one being the original one) will complete successfully:

```
$ kubectl patch mycrd.example.com test --type=json \
    -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/status", "value": {}}]'
mycrd.example.com/test patched
$ kubectl patch mycrd.example.com test --type=json \
    -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/status/foo", "value": "bar"}]'
mycrd.example.com/test patched
```

Obviously, `replace`ing the entire `.status` property with `{}` is not a good idea if that property already contains data that you want to keep.

A suitable alternative to a JSON patch in this scenario is a [JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386):

```
PATCH /apis/example.com/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/mycrd/test HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json
[other headers omitted for brevity...]

{
  "status": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

Or, alternatively, using `kubectl`:

```
$ kubectl patch mycrd.example.com test --type=merge \
    -p '{"status": {"foo": "bar"}}'
mycrd.example.com/test patched
```

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json-patch+json` this line actually helped me to figure it out how to patch the Kubernetes resource via Postman.